# if block not working in django view of python

Tags: python, if-statement, django-models, django-forms, django-views

```
def listingpage(request,title):   
    listings = Auctionlisting.objects.get(title=title)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Bidform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            bidmade = request.POST.get('bidmade')
            user = request.POST.get('username')
            username = User.objects.get(username=user)
            bid = Bid(user=username,bidmade=bidmade,bidobject=listings)
            if Bid.user != username and Bid.bidobject != listings:
                 bid.save()
                 return render(request, "auctions/listingpage.html",{
                 "listings":listings,
                 "bidform":form,
                 "message":"Your bid has been added in the auction..."
                 })
            
            else:
                return render(request,"auctions/error.html")
    else:
        form = Bidform()
    return render(request, "auctions/listingpage.html",{
    "listings":listings,
    "bidform":form
    })
```

can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code. if code is not working, it keeps on adding the bid even when it username and listing is already present in the bid database. i am using this code, in order to prevent more than once to place a bid on an object by a single username.

Comment: `Bid` is presumably a model class.  `Bid.user` is a *field definition* from that model; it cannot possibly be equal to `username`, no matter what name the user entered, because it does not represent any particular instance of the class.  The same thing applies to `Bid.bidobject`.  You need to perform a query on `Bid`, to see if there is any existing record with those two field values.

Comment: You are comparing values with fields. I guess you interested to use `bid` (lowercase) but then you are checking if the values are **not** what you set them one line before. What are you trying to do with the `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you only want to create a new `Bid` if the user has not created a bid for the specified listing, right?

```
bid, created = Bid.objects.get_or_create(user=username, bidobject=listings,
                                         defaults={"bidmade" : bidmade})
if created:
    return render(...)
else:
    #oops, that user has already bid on the listing, take appropriate action
```